# How do I maintain static directories on multisite subdomains?

Tags: multisite, filesystem, subdomains, customization

I'm trying to migrate from multiple subdomain blogs to WP multisite.  The one stumbling block is that I'm pretty sure the static files and directories on my subdomains will not be found; each of my blogs has its own set of static files (downloads, mp3 archives, scripts, etc.).  What would be a way to maintain these?

Will the following work?  I assume it will redirect anything with a `.` in it, no?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.org$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard WP RewriteRules ignore files and directories that "exist". Example:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This the rewrite rule set for a WP install in the "root" of a site. Notice these two lines in particular:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

These set the conditions that the file or directory being referenced must not exist. Thus, only files/directories that Apache doesn't find get rewritten to WordPress's index.php file.

So if Apache finds the file and can serve it directly, then it will, and WordPress will not get involved. So static links should remain as they are as long as the files are in the same place as before.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that; the problem is that I need to redirect files on the subdomains to the old subdomain directories, like `/var/www/sub1/file.mp3` if the request is `http://sub1.mysite.com/file.mp3`.  Since the subdomain no longer points to the sub1 directory, it's a little tricky.  Anyway, I think I have it working now with custom redirects.

Answer (score 0):

what I've done in the past is from the subdomain, I've exported all content. Then in the WP multisite, I've imported invluding all downloaded attachments. This seemed to have move over all my images and the like .

Comment: Thanks, but I'm talking about gigabytes of mp3s, etc.  I don't want to import them into wordpress, just have them accessible via their original url before switching to Network Install.